# How to access a usercontrol from another usercontrol in windows forms

Tags: c#

In my project, I have two usercontrol named controlA, controlB. In controlA contains two usercontrols and controlB contains one usercontrol.

In codebehind file I need a control for controlA usercontrol to controlB. How can access the ControlA usercontrol to controlB Codebehind. For this I created get set property for controlA usercontrol in controlB codebehind.How to set the reference for that to access the specific control in controlA to controlB.

Comment: You could take a leaf out of ActiveX control design and have your form class (site) implement some interface that the controls could query in which to discover other controls

Comment: Conceptually, the only difference between a `UserControl` and a `Form` is that you can't put a `Form` inside anything, while a `UserControl` can be contained in a container. The strategies for interaction between them are the same. Your question is really too broad, but inasmuch as it could be answered at all, your answers can be found on the marked duplicate. If you need more detailed help, you'll need to provide a more detailed question, including a good [mcve] and a clear explanation of what you've tried and what _specifically_ isn't working.